# CloudWatch Alarms based on file existence in Ec2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a requirement to monitor for a specific file in the `/mnt/file-i-need-to-monitor.txt` path where I need to;

1. Create alarms if the file doesn't exist anymore.

```
if [ ! -f /mnt/file-i-need-to-monitor.txt ]; then
    // create aws alarm and notify via an email
fi
```

How can I integrate this methodology?

I have looked into the `aws log agent` but it seems like it is for pushing any custom logs to a log group.

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello Jananath Banuka,

For your case, you can use aws cli to push a custom metric,
And you create an alert based on the console if this custom metric if you have > 1

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/put-metric-data.html

Comment: I got it, thanks. So, to clarify few things,`1. push a custom metric`, `2.create an alarm`. Is that it?

Comment: Yes @JananathBanuka, push the custom metric with the value 1 numeric, you perform the count in  the alarm part if you receive   value > 0 in 5 min you trigger the alarm

Comment: Two values should be either `1` or `0` right? `1` means file exist and `0` means file doesn't exist?

Comment: The best is use count value, once you get the file put data as value 1  like  :
"Value": 1  , and in your alert dashboard you test if count > 0